# How to Display Result of Query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm New Of codeigniter. I have trying to displaying output. It is not showing for written query. I have fetching some data from database. After fetch the, I try to show/echo data, but it's not show.

This is my code:

```
$iddss = $params['id'];
//print_r($iddss);
$cridit = $this->db->select('id, credit, firstName, lastName, email')
                   ->where('id', $iddss)
                   ->where('archived is NULL')
                   ->get('users')
                   ->row_array();
echo $cridit;  die;
```

Comment: you can use var_dump?

Comment: Vadivel. Ok i will try this

Comment: you should mention the key like this  echo $cridit['id'];  die;

Comment: Note that cod igniter is a tool or technique for setting fire to fish of the family gadidae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `row_array()` returns a single result row (as an array). 
>   If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row.

So

```
echo $cridit['credit'];// will print the value of credit column in the first row matching the where clause
```

> Read more about Codeigniter Query Results [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).